# Line appears in iOS 7 Textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, ios7

I have used the below code to display a colored placeholder within iOS Textfield. This works fine in iOS 5 and 6. But in iOS 7 a line appears in the middle of the Textfield.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [SEARCH_FIELD_FONT_COLOR setFill];
    if (self.placeholderFont) {
        [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:SEARCH_FIELD_FONT];
    }else {
        [[self placeholder] drawInRect:rect withFont:self.placeholderFont];
    }
}

@end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with following code for change color of placeholder of textFiled.

```
[self.myTextField setValue:[UIColor darkGrayColor] forKeyPath:@"_placeholderLabel.textColor"];
```

Comment: You are using a private field "_placeholderLabel". The app can be rejected.

Answer (score 0):

This could work a bit better. Also, you can change the font using and attributed placeholder.

```
- (void) drawPlaceholderInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [SEARCH_FIELD_FONT_COLOR setFill];

    [super drawPlaceholderInRect:rect];
}
```

Comment: @ChrisWagner I would file a bug, because this should work by the documentation.